# $X$ ascheme over field $k$. $L$ invertible sheaf over $X$, $O_X^{n+1}\to L$ surjection. There is $\phi:X\to P^n$ s.t. $\phi^\star(O_{P^n}(1))\cong L$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

This is related to Ueno's Algebraic Geometry Chpt 5, Exercise 5.33

Exercise 5.33 $P^n$ below means projective space over field $k$. Let $X$ be a scheme over field $k$. $L$ is invertible sheaf over $X$ with $O_X^{n+1}\to L$ surjection. Then there is $\phi:X\to P^n$ s.t. $\phi^\star(O_{P^n}(1))\cong L$.

The book quotes Thm 5.32. Suppose $g:Y\to X$ is given in the following and $Sym(E)$ is symmetric algebra generated by $E$ where $E$ is treated as $O_X$ module.

Thm 5.32. For a quasicoherent sheaf $E$ over scheme $X$, $P_E((Y,g))=\{(Y,\gamma)\vert$ $L$ is invertible sheaf over $Y$ s.t. $\gamma:g^\star(E)\to L$ surjective $O_Y$ map$\}/\sim$ where $(L,\gamma)\sim(L',\gamma')$ if there is $O_U$ isomorphism $h:L\to L'$ s.t. the diagram $g^\star(E)\to L\to L'$ and $g^\star(E)\to L'$ commutes. Furthermore, $Hom_X(Y,Proj(Sym(E)))\cong P_E((Y,g))$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ The book says "since $\gamma:O_X^{n+1}\to L$ is surjective $O_X$ morphism, by Thm 5.32, there is a scheme morphism $\phi:X\to P((O_X)^{n+1})=P^n_k$ so that $(L,\gamma)\sim (L'=\phi^\star(O_{P^n_k}(1)),\gamma_\phi)$. Hence $L\cong L'$." I do not get why $P((O_X)^{n+1})=P_k^n$ and why $(L,\gamma)\sim(L',\gamma_\phi)$

To me the problem is simply to cut $X$ into affine schemes and then piece together. WLOG, I can assume $X$ is affine say $X=Spec(R)$. Consider $g:Y=Spec(R)\to X=Spec(R)$ as identity map with $O_X^{n+1}$ as quasicoherent sheaf over $X$. Then $g^\star(O_X^{n+1})=O_X^{n+1}\to L$ is epimorphism with $L$ invertible sheaf over $Y$. From Thm 5.32's representability part, I have a morphism $\phi:Spec(R)\to Proj(Sym(\oplus R))$.

$\textbf{Issue 1:}$ Now I have $Sym(\oplus R)=R[x_0,\dots, x_n]$. Thus I see $Proj(Sym(\oplus R))=P^n_R$ instead of $P^n_k$. Did I get this part wrong?

$\textbf{Issue 2:}$ Over affine $X=Spec(R)$, clearly, there is epimorphism $R^{n+1}\to\phi^\star(O_{P^n_R}(1))=L'$ by observing that $\gamma(O_{P^n_R}(1),X)$ is free module of rank $n+1$ over $R$. Now the question is why $L'\cong L$ with induced diagram commutative?

$\textbf{Update:}$ I think the book was considering $X$ as a scheme over $k$ and use canonical embedding $k\to\Gamma(O_X,X)$ map to determine a morphism. Consider $\pi:X\to Spec(k)$ projection map. Then the book assume $\Gamma(X,L)$ is f.g. over $k$ as $n+1$ dimensional vector space which becomes a sheaf over $Spec(k)$. Hence consider $\pi^\star(\Gamma(X,L))=O_X^{n+1}$. This gives $\pi^\star(\Gamma(X,L))\to L$ epimorphism which gives rise to $\phi:X\to P^n_k$ map. However, I still do not see how to get $\phi^\star(O_{P^n_k)(1))\cong L$ as equivalence.